# Using Netcat for sending mail without having a 554 SMTP synchronization error

Tags: email, smtp, delay, interactive, netcat

I am trying to use Netcat for sending an e-mail. With a smtp server it just goes
fine, but with another it gives a "554 SMTP synchronization error". The reason
is the smtp server should send proper RFC0854 codes before to receive answer from netcat.
I need then to ask netcat to wait the server answer for every step, but I did not figure out how.
I tried with the -i option, but it does not work.

That is my command:

nc smpt.myserver.com 25 < myfile

(I saved on the file all the code I need to send throguh smtp)

I also tried with an expect script (either using spawn telnet or spawn nc) , but the problem is that, for an unknown reason, if my code is too long (more than 200k), the 
telnet/netcat session breakdown while sending data (with no error code).

This problem is solved if use
nc smpt.myserver.com 25 < myfile
(but as I said before it gives 554 error with a specific server)

Do you have any clue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"?  And what version of netcat are you using (I'm using the "classic" version (by Hobbit) and connecting to a local exim4, `-i 1` works for me.